# 360 Continuous Rotation Servo only goes 180 degrees

Tags: arduino, servomotor

I bought the following servo: [D DOLITY High Speed 360 Degree Continuous Rotation Servo for Robotic(15kg/cm) Metal Gears Servo](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07N2PLF6W/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1#detail_bullets_id)

I'm trying to get it to spin in one direction continuously, but it looks like it can only go 180 degrees and then stops.

Is there something wrong with my code that is making it stop at 180 degrees or is the product falsely advertised as a 360° continuous rotation servo?

This is the Arduino code I'm using:

```
Servo myservo;  //Servo name is myservo

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo signal pin on pin D6
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("0");// You can display on the serial the signal value
  myservo.write(0); //Turn clockwise at high speed
}
```

Comment: run code for normal servo and see what happens ... set to 30 degrees, wait a second, set to 90 degrees, wait a second ... repeat  .... you should have done that before posting your question ... it is a part of debugging

Comment: I did do that. That works fine. The issue I'm having is it won't continuously spin in a direction. Eg. It won't go beyond 180 degrees.

Comment: Because i'm new at this, i want to make sure that i'm not doing something wrong in my code. It would help if someone verified. On Amazon, its advertised as a 360 degrees continuous servo motor. So is it advertised or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already determined that the servo acts as a positional servo, and not as a continuous rotation servo, then it is not a continuous rotation servo.